# angularjs ng-options nested json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, drop-down-menu, ng-options

I am using AngularJS for my web app. My objective is to have two dropdowns list using `ng-options`.

- The first dropdown showing the country list
- The other gives the language preferences for the selected country

Being still new to AngularJS, I am able to display the data but the entire object is displayed as a single option, I am unable to split each data.

Kindly find the code below that I used.

### HTML

```
<select ng-model="selectedRegion" ng-options="region.countryName for region in eyebrow.regionSelector"></select>
<select ng-model="selectedRegion.selectLang" ng-options= "selectedRegion.selectLang for region in selectedRegion track by selectedRegion.countryName"></select>
```

### JS:

```
angular.module ('appngOption')
.controller ('headerController', function($scope) {
  $scope.eyebrow = { regionSelector: [
  {
     "id": 1,
     "countryName": "Belgium",
     "selectLang": ["Dutch", "English", "French"]
  },{
     "id": 2,
     "countryName": "France",
     "selectLang": ["English", "French"]
  }]}
});
```

*Example*: Dutch, English and French should be each separate dropdown option when Belgium is selected.
&  English and French should be each separate dropdown option when France is selected.

Kindly review the code and let me know if i had missed anything. Your help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed some issues in your code.

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/dxah4p7c/1/)

The first input was correct:

```
<select ng-model="selectedRegion" ng-options="region.countryName for region in eyebrow.regionSelector"></select>
```

But in the second, I changed several things:

- Set `ng-model` to a different variable (`selectLang`), it's cleaner.
- `ng-options` loops over `selectedRegion.regionSelector`, instead of just `selectedRegion`. That was your main mistake here:

```
<select ng-model="selectLang" ng-options="lang for lang in selectedRegion.selectLang"></select>
```

Comment: That helped a lot.
Will I be able to set a default value when a country is selected, for example when I select Belgium, can I have the language set to French.